# How to reliably catch "breakpoints" for multi-threaded application in Visual Studio? (C++, VS2008)

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a multi-threaded application that I'm debugging inside the IDE (Visual Studio 2008, Win7-64, C++).

For "debugging" purposes, I "pretend" that I always have a single processor (the program detects the number of local processors), but the program design establishes a *minimum* of two threads (e.g., the "main thread" which handles GUI and event traffic, and a second "processing" thread where work is moved off of the "main thread").  *(In a "production" build there would be a single main thread, and one-or-more "processing" threads depending on the number of detected processors.)*

**ISSUE:**  Breakpoints in the code (within the IDE) *sometimes* are triggered, and *sometimes* not.  Re-running the program may "catch" on a break point where the previous run it did not "catch" (no source code changes or rebuild is performed to see this change-in-breakpoint-catch-behavior, the program execution path is identical).

*(I mostly only care about triggering breakpoints in the non-GUI/non-main-thread, but I assume that should not matter.)*

**QUESTION:**  **Is there a way to make these break points catch more "reliably"?  (What influences whether a break point "catches" or not?)**

I'm aware of, and NOT concerned with the following:

- Source is out-of-sync with latest linked executable
- Build is not "debug" (no debug symbols available)
- "Clean build" is needed (debug artifacts out-of-date)
- "Step Over/Into" may not work properly when another thread "breaks"
  during that first thread's stepping operation

On web searches, there was a mention of possibly setting the compiler setting to "`x86`" and not "`Any Processor`" to catch breakpoints, not sure why that might matter ... ?

Finally, yes, of course, all logic "should" be tested in a single-threaded application (e.g., re-factor to ensure deterministic single-threaded execution for unit and regression tests).  However, for the current testing, I *need* to be in the "real" application (think "integration testing" or "systems integration").

Comment: Not that this is any kind of answer, but I have done a lot of debugging of multithreaded code in VS2005 and VS2010 and some in VS2008 but not as much.  I don't think I have ever encountered a situation where a breakpoint was triggered intermittently.  I have never had to "do" anything to make breakpoints work; they just always work (they are only "intermittent" if they are conditional breakpoints).  So my immediate suspicion would be that the code you think is running and should trigger a breakpoint is not actually running.

Comment: @Mark, it's a command-line application with the same data, and the execution path is identical. The code *is* running (I have "trace" statements to prove it), but only sometimes catching. Weird. (I don't have any conditions on the breakpoints either.) It's a big program, though, not sure if that should matter ...

Comment: It is certainly strange.  Is it managed C++ perhaps?  About 98.2% of the debugging I was referring to that I have done is with unmanaged code.

Comment: @Mark, all standard ISO C++ (no managed, no inter-op with any other language)

Comment: Does the intermittent behavior ever occur within a single execution?  Or is it always between runs?  In other words, if it stops on a breakpoint in a given execution of the program, will it stop every time during that execution?

Comment: @Mark, within a single execution: It's skipped in one run, but not in another. If the code runs ten times, it breaks all ten times, or none of them. (So yes, it *is* consistent, which is good, I think?)

Comment: I really have no good ideas.  One possibility might be to delete all breakpoints (under the debug menu) and then reset them.  And now the SO site is telling me to avoid extended discussions in comments.  I wonder why; it seems like having this information directly associated with the post would be better.

Comment: Does it switch from working to not working without recompiling? This is a key bit of info. If recompiling messes it up, try running http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html on the exe and the pdb file. If you can catch a mismatch, there's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally breaking is extremely reliable. Here are some things to try:

1. Hard code a breakpoint with DebugBreak(). This should always be caught, but if this exhibits the same broken behavior, you have narrowed down the problem.
2. Where you currently have the bp set, add a line to print to screen/file, and set the breakpoint on that line. This is to be *certain* this line is really even being hit. You may have a strange, unexpected bug that is actually skipping the entire section unexpectedly and this is necessary to be sure.
3. Try with and without any optimizations. Debugging works best with all optimizations off, but even with deadstripping and inlining features at work, breakpoints are expected to still work. Does this issue occur even with optimizations off?
4. You say ISO C++, does this mean you've actually switched off all microsoft extensions? I've never compiled this way in visual studio, but if you have, try switching extensions back on and see if that has any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to agree with VoidStar and other comments. I have worked with VC6, VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 and I have debugged pretty complex multi-threaded apps with them and breakpoints have always been reliable for me.

With once exception. For projects that use DLLs, sometimes breakpoints that are set in code from a DLL do not work. This is not because VS misses the breakpoint, but instead because the debugger cannot map that line of code to an actual location in the compiled code, probably because the pdb file could not be loaded for some reason. When this happens you see a hollow red circle in the left margin of the breakpoint line instead of the full red ball. Could this be your problem?

I have not figured out why this happens sometimes, but in my experience it only happens for breakpoints in modules that are not the main project being debugged. A workaround that I use is to start the debugger from the DLL, putting the exe in the startup debug configuration for the DLL project. Another trick that sometimes helps is to have all the projects in a single solution, and have them all setup with correct references, so that with one compilation you can rebuild the whole thing.

Good luck, I hope this helps.